# Conditionals of dynamic content with PUG and FLASK

Tags: flask, pug, prepros

This is the flask file.

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'nickname': 'Miguel'}  # fake user
    return render_template('index.html',title='Home',user=user)
```

This is pug file:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        title pageTitle

        if title
            title {{ title }} - microblog
        else if !title
            title Welcome to microblog1
        else
            title Welcome to microblog2

    body
    h1 Hello,  {{ user.nickname }}!
    if {{ user.nickname }} == "Miguel"
        h1 Miguel
```

This is what the index.html looks like once converted with Prepros:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>pageTitle</title>
        <title>Welcome to microblog1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello,  {{ user.nickname }}!</h1>
        <h1>{{ user.nickname }}</h1>
        <h1># user.nickname</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can get dynamic content from FLASK with my PUG file.
So the following in the script works:

```
h1 Hello,  {{ user.nickname }}!
```

The output is "Hello, Miguel!"

but this part doesn't work.

```
if {{ user.nickname }} == "Miguel"
        h1 Miguel
```

I get a syntax error: Unexpected token. So I can get the name from Flask, but I can't use it in an if statement?
I'm not sure if I'm doings something wrong or if it's just not supported. 
Btw, I'm using Prepros(which is giving the error) to convert my PUG file to HTML.

Something that might be related is that when I do convert my file via Prepros, I don't really get the result I would expect.

This is from the PUG file:

```
title pageTitle
if title
    h1 {{ title }}
else if !title
    title Welcome to microblog1
```

In the html I would expect:

```
<title>pageTitle</title>
{% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
{% else if !title %}
    <title> Welcome to microblog1
```

but I end up with:

```
<title>pageTitle</title>
<title>Welcome to microblog1</title>
```

It's as if Prepros answers the IF statement before converting to HTML. Which means the code is not dynamic. I'm new to both PUG and FLASK, so I'm not sure where to try find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. Found the solution.

```
| {% if user.nickname == 'Miguels'%}
|   h1 Miguel
| {% endif %}
```

This then comes out in the HTML as:

```
{% if user.nickname == 'Miguels'%}
    h1 Miguel
{% endif %}
```

This also solves the issue of answering the IF statement in the conversion.

@cs01
Thanks, that article was where I found the solution. The "-" didn't work.

@Shea Belsky
Thanks. I knew it existed since it "printed" it with:

```
h1 user.nickname
```

Answer (score 0):

Double curly braces `{{ }}` is not valid Pug syntax. (I think it's part of another HTML preprocessor, I don't remember what off the top of my head). In Pug, the two curly braces prefixed by a pound symbol `#{}` indicate code that you can run to return something. Your source pug file would look like this, then:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        title pageTitle

        if title
            title #{ title } - microblog
        else if !title
            title Welcome to microblog1
        else
            title Welcome to microblog2

    body
    h1 Hello,  #{ user.nickname }!
    if #{ user.nickname } == "Miguel"
        h1 Miguel
```

You do not need to use that syntax when indicating a variable inside of a loop or conditional. You can do just `if variable === "something"`, and that should work just fine.

In your example, you would change your if statement to not have any curly braces.

```
if user.nickname == "Miguel"
    h1 Miguel
```

If you're always going to be having an `h1` for the user's nickname, you can just embed it directly using those curly braces.

```
h1 #{user.nickname}
```

Lastly, you have two `title` elements in your code, which is why it's coming up twice. You can take out the topmost one (`title pageTitle`) in order for only one to appear, where the content is dependent on there being a valid `title` variable passed to the processor.

Comment: Blesky
Thanks for the reply! I tried those suggestions.
    if user.nickname == "Miguel"
That gives me a "Error: Cannot read property 'nickname' of undefined.
    if #{ user.nickname } == "Miguel"
That gives me "Error: Syntax Error: Unexpected character '#'".
I'm just wondering if it's something from Prepros struggling to convert it?

Comment: You should first check if `user` exists. Try this: `-console.log(user);` on a new line: `if user && user.nickname == "Miguel"`. The `console.log` will be in your server console (IDE, Terminal, CMD, etc), not your client-side console (browser).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `-` character.

```
if {{ user.nickname }} == "Miguel"
        h1 Miguel
```

would be

```
- if user.nickname == 'Miguel'
    h1 Miguel
```

Source: https://github.com/matannoam/pypugjs#using-templatetags-and-any-feature-of-the-compiled-to-language

```
Using templatetags (and any feature of the compiled-to language)

Using Django and crispy-forms as an illustrative example but the information can be generalized.

If you need to use templatetags, you can use PugJS's syntax for rendering code:

- load crispy_forms_tags
- crispy form
This will compile into

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy form %}
If you have any trouble with this feature, or there's some feature of your template language that is being misinterpreted when using this syntax, you can also do something like this:

| {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
| {% crispy form %}
This will compile into the same Django template snippet.
```